# $\pi_j(G_{cont}/G_{finite})$

Tags: manifolds, lie-groups, homotopy-theory, quotient-spaces, exact-sequence

For the quotient group $$G'=G_{cont}/G_{finite},$$ knowing the homotopy
groups of $G_{cont}$ and $G_{finite}$, one can determine homotopy groups from the long exact sequence

$$
...
\to \pi_n(G_{finite})     \to \pi_n(G_{cont})     \to \pi_n(G')
\to \pi_{n-1}(G_{finite}) \to \pi_{n-1}(G_{cont}) \to \pi_{n-1}(G') \to ....
$$
But in practice, one needs to be careful about the map.

Let us take one example,

> $$G'=SU(N)/\mathbb{Z}_N,$$

where $\mathbb{Z}_N$ is a normal subgroup of $SU(N)$.

$$
...
\to \pi_1(\mathbb{Z}_N)     \to \pi_1(SU(N))     \to \pi_1(G')
\to \pi_{0}(\mathbb{Z}_N) \to \pi_{0}(SU(N)) \to \pi_{0}(G') 
$$

Are the following statements correct:

$$
...
\to \pi_1(\mathbb{Z}_N)=0     \to \pi_1(SU(N))=0     \to \pi_1(G')
\to \pi_{0}(\mathbb{Z}_N)=\mathbb{Z}_N \to \pi_{0}(SU(N))=0 \to \pi_{0}(G') 
$$

so

$$
...
\to 0     \to 0     \to \pi_1(G')
\to \mathbb{Z}_N \to 0 \to \pi_{0}(G') 
$$

> Questions:
>
> 1. $\pi_{0}(G')=0?$
> 2. $\pi_{1}(G')=\mathbb{Z}_N?$
> 3. $\pi_{2}(G')=\pi_{2}(SU(N))?$
> 4. $\pi_{j}(G')=\pi_{j}(SU(N))?$, 
>      for $j\geq 2.$
>
> Am I correct for the above equalities?